# using $.data("value") versus $.attr("data-value")

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

When I use `jQuery.data` to change the value the attribute in the DOM doesn't change.
But I like when the attribute in the DOM changes, its much easier to debug stuff.

So is it ok to use `$().attr("data-value")` to change data-attributes?

Just a little fiddle to show that mixing `$().attr` and `$().data` won't work well together:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvRJc/

Comment: when you use `.data()` the data is stored in an internal data structure in jQuery that is why mixing those 2 does not work

Comment: That `$().data` reads the initial value of data-* attributes is just a convenient feature. Use whatever you want as long as your are consistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `data` function manages a cache of data for an element that jQuery provides, not `data-*` attributes. The only interconnection between the `data` function and `data-*` attributes is that `data` will *initialize* its cache of information from `data-*` attributes if you request a key that matches a `data-*` attribute.

Using `data` to *set* data will never update a `data-*` attribute.

It's fine to use `attr` to update the attribute, you just need to be consistent: Either use the *attribute* (via `attr`) for both getting and setting, **or** use `data` for both getting and setting, as they manage different things.

Using `attr` means you're really updating the attribute on the element, which means you can use the values you set in selectors and such (both CSS and jQuery), but also means you are limited to getting and setting only string values.

Using `data` means you're only updating the data cache, not the element, which means you *can't* use those values in selectors and such (because they're not stored anywhere in the DOM), but means you can get and set the full range of JavaScript data types.